# Types of VS FoxPro encodings

Tags: encoding, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I'm trying to decode some strings in a DBF (created by a Foxpro app), and i'm interested in encoding / encrypting methods of FoxPro.

Here's a sample encoded string: "òÙÛÚÓ ½kê3ù[ƒ˜øžÃ+™Þoa-Kh— Gó¯ý""|øHñyäEük@‰fÃ§9æ×Ï¯yi±:"

Can somebody tell me the encoding method of this string, OR give me any suggestion about Foxpro encoding methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the FoxPro version, the most recent DBF structure (VFP 9) is documented here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa975386%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your text could be the result of the "_Crypt.vcx" which will take a given string, apply whatever passphrase and generate an output encrypted string.

VFP has a class that is available in the "FFC" folder where VFP is default installed (via HOME() path resulting such as

```
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL FOXPRO 9\
```

Here is a SAMPLE set of code to hook up the _Crypt class and sample to encrypt a string, then decrypt an encrypted string.  Your string appears encrypted (obviously), but unless you know more of the encryption (such as finding the passphrase / key, you might be a bit stuck and into more research)...

```
lcCryptLib = HOME() + "FFC\_Crypt.vcx"
IF NOT FILE( lcCryptLib )
    MESSAGEBOX( "No crypt class library." )
    RETURN 
ENDIF 
SET CLASSLIB TO ( lcCryptLib ) ADDITIVE 

oCrypt = CREATEOBJECT( "_CryptAPI" )
oCrypt.AddProperty( "myPassKey" )
oCrypt.myPassKey = "Hold property to represent some special 'Key/pass phrase' "

*/ Place-holder to get encrypted value
lcEncryptedValue = ""
? oCrypt.EncryptSessionStreamString( "Original String", oCrypt.myPassKey, @lcEncryptedValue )

*/ Show results of encrypted value
? "Encrypted Value: " + lcEncryptedValue 

*/ Now, to get the decrypted from the encrypted...
lcDecryptedValue = ""
? oCrypt.DecryptSessionStreamString( lcEncryptedValue, oCrypt.myPassKey, @lcDecryptedValue )

? "Decrypted Value: " + lcDecryptedValue


*/ Now, try with your string to decrypt
lcYourString = [òÙÛÚÓ ½kê3ù[ƒ˜øžÃ+™Þoa-Kh— Gó¯ý""|øHñyäEük@‰fÃ§9æ×Ï¯yi±:]
lcDecryptedValue = ""
? oCrypt.DecryptSessionStreamString( lcYourString, oCrypt.myPassKey, @lcDecryptedValue )

? "Decrypted Value: " + lcDecryptedValue
```